# Initializing pointer arrays to NULL within a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, null

Given the struct declaration (where `data` is an array of pointers to another struct):

```
typedef struct {
    B* data[10];
} A;
```

It seems that pointer arrays within structs are not automatically initialized to NULL:

```
struct A myA;
myA.data[0] == NULL (false!)
```

Is there a way to enforce that the array is initialized to NULLs without doing it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object of any type can be initialized to zero:

```
struct A myA = { 0 };
```

This initializes the first scalar member or element (defined recursively for nested arrays, structures, and unions) to `0` converted to the appropriate type, which is a null pointer value if it's a pointer. All remaining members or elements are also initialized to zero.

Some compilers may warn you about the missing initializers; since `= { 0 }` is, or should be a common idiom for "initialize everything to zero", you can ignore the warning.

Comment: NULL is not guaranteed to be represented by all 0 bits

Comment: @rowan.G: I'm well aware of that. But `0` is a null pointer constant; it will be implicitly converted to the appropriate pointer type, and that conversion is guaranteed to yield a null pointer value.

Comment: you are correct, my information was wrong. seems like I have been writing to0 much bloat code for months...